# Michtav Me’Eliyahu on the Destruction of Edom

Tags: sources-mekorot, jewish-books

Rabbi Eliyahu Eliezer Dessler writes in Michtav Me’Eliyahu the following:

*"The destruction of Edom [at the end of our last exile] will only come through the destruction of this world [as we know it]. the Holy One will cause the very foundations of life on earth to collapse. Tranquility will be disrupted, personal lives will be filled with worry, fear and suffering, and the entire world will cower in dread of destruction and devastation… Only then will the light of the Messiah be revealed … ‘and the saviors shall go up to Mount Zion to judge the mountain of Esau…’”*

Does anyone know where this can be found in the Michtav Me’Eliyahu?

Comment: Where did you see this quoted?

Comment: What makes you think that this quotation exists in Michtav Me'Eliyahu? Please [edit] to show the basis of this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is in Cheilek 3 page 205. The name of the chapter is "Galus Vigeulah".

Comment: @ChiddusheiTorah my pleasure

Comment: Is it possible for you to send me a link for it?

Comment: @ChiddusheiTorah I don't know if it's available online (I found it in the book itself)